# ¿Como alojo mi sitio web en un servicio de hosting (alojamiento)?

Tags: php, html5, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tengo mi sitio web (html5, css3, js, php, codeigniter). Soy un estudiante principiante en esta área de desarrollo web y me gustaría saber como es posible alojar mi sitio web a un servicio de hosting gratuito.

Agradecería encales sobre servicios de hosting gratuitos y tutoriales
si es posible.

Gracias!

Comment: Felicitaciones! y bienvenido al mundo del desarrollo de software! Hosting sencillitos y gratuitos para practicar: www.hostinger.com  www.000webhost.com, con respecto al tema de tutoriales, te recomiendo que te pasees por Youtube, no importa el idioma en el que se encuentre el video, con tal que puedas observar los pasos que hacen y captes la idea, jugando se aprende :) una sugerencia que puedo darte es que tengas mucha paciencia ya que en cada problema que aparezca la necesitaras en su máxima expresión. Bendiciones!

Comment: @fredyfx Hola amigo, gracias por tus cálidos consejos,

En estos momentos estoy utilizando http://www.hostinger.es/ , estoy siguiendo un breve tutorial en **Youtube** para montar mi sitio. Por ahora, el primer **bug** que tengo es ´mysqli::real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.2.1.41 (using password: NO)´, con mi base de datos y mi usuario.

Comment: Esta pregunta seguramente acabará cerrada porque, aunque está relacionada con el proceso de programación en general, Es demasiado amplia (muchas posibles soluciones diferentes) y atrae más opiniones que hechos. Aunque quizás si concretases un poco más el método a seguir, podría Ser una buena referencia para otros usuarios en el futuro

Answer (score 3):

Yo estoy utilizando alojamiento gratuito para mis prácticas de la universidad desde este [Hosting](https://byet.host/).

Solo ingresa a la página, regístrate y te creará una extensión de su propio dominio, pero con el nombre de tu página. Se te enviarán los datos de acceso FTP a tu cuenta de correo electrónico. Puedes usar un cliente FTP como Filezilla para hacer el manejo de tu dominio desde tu ordenador.

Es recomendable manejar tu dominio desde un cliente `FTP` pues tienes un respaldo del desarrollo de tu página de manera local por si el servicio gratuito se diera de baja.

Pasos:

1. Desarrollas tu página.
2. Te Registras en el Hosting Gratuito.
3. Instalas Filezilla.
4. Ingresas al Hosting por medio de Filezilla utilizando los datos de acceso que te enviaron a tu correo.
5. Cargas los archivos de tu página.
6. Ingresar a la URL de tu página y verificas la actualización.

Para aprender a usar Filezilla, te dejo esta [liga](https://clientes.wiroos.com/knowledgebase/28/iComo-se-utiliza-el-programa-FileZilla.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, utilizaré **FTP**

Comment: Por nada amigo yo también estoy empezando con el desarrollo web, el punto es no dejar de aprender. Saludos.

Comment: Si deseas aprender a alojar tu sitio web de forma gratuita y como conectarlo con tu dominio a través de un registrador de dominios y actualizando el DNS con Hostinger. Este tutorial te enseña todo lo que necesitas incluyendo como funciona el internet y varias opciones alternativas:

youtube.com/watch?v=8wOhVltQ7lM

Answer (score 1):

Existen muchos sitios que ofrecen hosting gratuito o dominio gratuito, pero rara vez ambos, así que te recomiendo además de buscar un hosting precario como hostinger o webhost adquirir un dominio gratuito, por ejemplo en http://www.dot.tk/es/index.html?lang=es regalan dominios con extensión `.tk`
que son fáciles de configurar con las herramientas de los dos sitios que te mencioné.

(No estoy seguro de que tengan codeigniter porque tiene bastante que no lo uso)

Normalmente estos sitios cuentan con la herramienta `cpanel` que contiene administradores para configurar el sitio, desde cuentas de correo, certificados ssh, dominios referenciados, subdominios, cuentas ftp, bases de datos, y plugins.

Mi sincera opinión es que si vas a usar extensivamente y por un largo tiempo el hospedaje web con fines de lucro en mente, inviertas en algún sitio de paga que te incluya ya ambos aspectos por ejemplo hostgator, pues normalmente estos servicios se esmeran con sus clientes.

### Alternativas de estudiantes tercermundistas c#$%#$% y luchones, enfierrados y alterados

Siendo un poco más sinceros y brutalmente francos, para tus proyectos estudiantiles normalmente no necesitarás un servicio que esté disponible las 24 horas del día y soporte a más de mil personas al mismo tiempo especialmente si no vas a recibir la más mínima retribución económica por ello, así que la opción más barata es optar por alguna de las siguientes opciones que te harán aprender y te darán el ancho para cualquier tecnología que elijas.

Puedes usar sevicios como el de noip.com, que te permiten tener un servidor dns apuntando a tu computadora personal, si abres los puertos de tu modem/router y ejecutas su programa unos minutos antes de que lo necesites podrás acceder a tu computadora con un dominio del tipo `miservidordeestudiante.noip.com` desde por lo menos tu país y unos cuantos países cercanos. Soporta normalmente cerca de 9 personas al mismo tiempo sin que se afecte el rendimiento para todos ( incluido tu ordenador personal ).

Mi opción predilecta, aunque un poco más compleja y temeraria es usar TOR con Vidalia ( se bajan en el sitio del tor, antes venían juntos pero ahora los separaron ) que te permitirá hacer que tu computadora se convierta en un servidor web en la darknet TOR, un pseudo paraiso de los hackers, tu sitio podría verse en cualquier parte del mundo desde esta darknet, tu dirección se genera algo así http://daso122ago24u1d1gsZSFud.onion y será accesible siempre que tu pc esté encendida, estés conectado a la red TOR y estés sirviendo páginas con vidalia. Su única desventaja es que como todas las comunicaciones están cifradas y redirigidas se muestra muy lento... es como el Internet en los 80, justo antes de que surgiera google.

La última opción es algo similar, usando freenet, otra darknet menos popular puedes montar tu servidor y lograr mayores velocidades dependiendo de la cantidad de personas que lo consulten y estén conectadas a esta darknet. Tiene la ventaja de que tiene su propio programa aparte para configurar el servidor, como ventaja normalmente la freenet no consume tanto tu ancho de banda como el TOR.